# Active Directory rendom /upload "Search to find Configuration container failed"

Tags: active-directory

I'm trying to rename our Active Directory domain, following the instructions here:
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1347.renaming-a-windows-server-2008-active-directory-domain-dsforum2wiki.aspx
(as well as several others that I've looked for when I've run into problems)

I download the forest information with rendom /list
Then I do a search and replace to get the new domain name configured.
rendom /showforest shows me a new forest tree that looks good.
When I run "rendom /upload", I get this error:

```
C:\donrem>rendom /upload
Search to find Configuration container failed: The system cannot find the file specified. :2
```

Checking with adsiedit.msc, I can see that the Configuration container was found, and the msDS-UpdateScript property gets updated with some code, so obviously the rendom command is able to find it and change it.

I have searched, but found no reference to this error, so I suspect my Active Directory is messed up.
Does anyone have suggestions to move forward?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. Why are you renaming your domain. I've found that 90%+ of the time, a domain rename is unnecessary and because of the various complexities and issues that can arise with a domain rename and how important your AD infrastructure generally is, it is generally not wise to rename your domain.
2. Have you verified that you have an entry for every DC in your whole forest dclist.xml and that the state was set to initial? (and made sure the file was in your working directory)
3. Are you a member of the Enterprise Admins on the forest?
4. Did you make sure you had valid backups prior to starting this? Did you test to make sure you could recover your forest before you started this?

Comment: Hi, holidays got in the way.
1. We don't NEED to rename the AD, but it currently uses a domain name that we don't have anymore (long story). We want to have our servers with the same name externally and internally.
2. I need to check that, but from memory, the file looked correct.
3. Yes, I was using the main Enterprise Admin account.
4. Yes, we had backups, so we are back where we started :)

Comment: Answer to number 2: dclist.xml does not get created. It should get created precisely at that point, when I execute "rendom /upload" with the modified Domainlist.xml, but it doesn't get created.